# Deleting an Excel Row if the year of the cell value is less than a specific year

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to iterate over specific cells with a date value and delete the rows where the year value of the date is less than 2020.

I can get the years with .year method and can find the row numbers of the cells that satisfy my statement which are integers, however when I use .delete_rows() method, I get a traceback error stating

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'year'**

This code works and gives me the row numbers of the cells that have a smaller year value than 2020

```
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
maxColumn = sheet.max_column
maxRow = sheet.max_row

for row in range(2, maxRow):
    cell = sheet.cell(row,4)
    cell_year = cell.value.year
    if cell_year < 2020:
        print(row)
```

But this gives Traceback:

```
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
maxColumn = sheet.max_column
maxRow = sheet.max_row

for row in range(2, maxRow):
    cell = sheet.cell(row,4)
    cell_year = cell.value.year
    if cell_year < 2020:
        sheet.delete_rows(row)
```

I know I can create a list with the row numbers and create another loop to delete those selected rows but I want to know what is my mistake.

I would appreciate if you can help me through this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you're facing is that you repeat your process for the size of the datset, but then reduce the dice of the dataset, so that your program tries to make changes to lines that dont exist. To fix this i would recommend you first add the number of the lines you want to delete to an array, and then have a loop that goes through that array and deletes the lines.

Comment: This is correct. Another alternative is to iterate backwards through your range: for row in range(maxRow, 2, -1):

Comment: It makes sense now, so delete_rows doesnt fully delete the row before the loop iterates over the next process therefore it reads empty cell values and gives the error. Thank you for the alternative routes.